# how can i run the send email process after one page item refreshes

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, process, oracle-apex

i have a dynamic action that makes a new html table of interactive report after every change on my interactive report,
and i write the table on hidden page item and select it as items to return in dynamic actions.

everything is okay for now,

then i have send email process,when i add one more row in my interactive report it also works but it sends the old table,
basically it is sending the email before page item could not change,

if i make delay , does it work? if it works how can i delay the process,

or anyone can help?

i hope i could explain

Comment: the help page seems complete and help ful https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/apex-send-email.html#GUID-060AC41F-4C3A-44E6-992C-B0CC2DB5B73E where are you struggeling exactly

Comment: What you describe can be resolved using AJAX callback. Check this https://tm-apex.hashnode.dev/ajax-callback as it is a good starting point if you are not familiar with it.